# Jupyter notebook with pyspark throws Unicode Warning on Windows

Tags: windows, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running PySpark in a Jupyter notebook on Windows. Anytime I execute a Spark action (e.g. `rdd.take(n)` or `rdd.count()`), I get a Unicode Warning in the Command Prompt.

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

For example, the following code, which produces the correct output, throws the warning:

```
%%time
distFile = sc.textFile(pth, use_unicode=False)
distFile = distFile.map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
distFile.take(10)
```

Here `pth` is the path to a tab-delimited text file.

If I run a larger task, say `rdd.count()` or `rdd.collect()`, the Unicode Warning is displayed after every task is completed! Then the console output is of the following form:

```
[Stage 30:================>                      (1483 + 32) / 2272]
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal 
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal 
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal 
[Stage 30:================>                      (1484 + 32) / 2272]
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal 
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal 
C:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py:48: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

...and so on.

I suspect this is a problem with the Jupyter setup because I **don't receive the Unicode Warning if I run the above code directly in the spark interpreter**. Does anyone know of a way to address this problem?

OS: Windows Server 2012 
Python version 2.7.12 
Anaconda version 4.2.0 (64-bit) 
Jupyter notebook 4.2.3 
Spark version 2.0.2

Comment: Are pyspark shell and jupyter using the same pyton interpreter?

Comment: @Mariusz Hm, good question. I _think_ so, but how would I check that?

Comment: Add `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` in pyspark shell and then in jupyter